# How to make python2 find the old python-gtop?

Tags: 20.04, python-2.7

I'd like to install `python-gtop` from the old

```
python-gtop_2.32.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

but that has a dependency on python (< 2.8)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-gtop : Depends: python (>= 2.7)
               Depends: python (< 2.8)
               Depends: python-gtk2 but it is not installed
```

and Ubuntu 20.04 has python3 and python2 but not python (< 2.8).

---

I can see that the old python-gtop_2.32.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb` provides

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtop.so
/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gtk-2.0/gtop.so
```

Where do they need to go in Ubuntu 20.04, and how do I make python2 see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by downloading and installing all necessary dependencies manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-gtop_2.32.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgtop2/libgtop2-7_2.28.5-2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libgtop2-7_2.28.5-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtop_2.32.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Looks like I missed the python-gtk2 dependency, thanks.